# Is it ever OK to call a model class method from within a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I was in the process of implementing a slide show for my spree store, when I came across a gem that does it. In part of the ReadMe file, I noticed it calls a model class method directly from the view: https://github.com/priviterag/spree_slider#or-roll-your-own

Here's the code:

```
<% if Spree::Slide.published.count > 0 %>
  <section id="slideshow">
    <ul class="slide">
      <% Spree::Slide.published.order('position ASC').each do |s| %>
        <li>
          <h1><%= s.slide_name %></h1>
          <%= link_to image_tag(s.slide_image.url), url_for(s.slide_link) %>
        </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
    <a title="<%= t(:previous) %>" class="slider-prev"><%= t(:previous)%></a>
    <a title="<%= t(:next) %>" class="slider-next"><%= t(:next) %></a>
  </section>
<% end %>
```

I was doing the same with my own slider, but had flagged the model call as something to move into the relevant controllers (there'd be a few) later. However, really, it seems like it's most self-contained, and easiest to understand and maintain, when the model is called directly from the view like this.

I'd always been lead to believe a View accessing a Model class directly gave good programers nightmares. But in this context, is fetching data directly from the view OK? Why or why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most things passed into Rails views are AREL proxy objects, via which the data is fetched and returned when they are rendered in the view. In that respect, "fetching data directly from the view" is not only acceptable, it's the norm, if your question is about the ordering of events and what actually happens.

But I think what you are getting at is: why should Views be isolated from Models? What bad things happen when they are not?

There are a lot of patterns related to MVC but different. (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) MV is one such example. In MV, views know all about models but models don't know about views. You could write an entire application with the MV pattern. A small one maybe. :P The example you posted looks like MV.

I honestly feel like MVC dos and donts gets to firebrand rules lawyering from software architects really quickly. It frustrates me. People should calm down and consider their options. I recommend reading Refactoring by Martin Fowler if you haven't, and I think reading up about the history of MVC and Presentation Model would be fruitful also. MVC is not the only game in town. You should break out classes when it's useful to do so but also collapse and merge classes when you overengineered. In that vein, I think there are times when MV is adequate and MVC is overkill. Little examples pasted onto the web may be one such time, even though some people may interpret them a little bit too literally when transplanting them into a bigger application.

MVC can handle situations where the complexity of the application is such that separating out every niggling little concern is the only way to manage the sheer amount of code involved. The presumption of MVC is that your app is going to be big and complex. Think about apps like Microsoft Word. In that context, you may have an MDI (Multiple Document Interface) scenario where there are multiple views of the same model that need to be kept in sync via events. You may have different kinds of models that can be rendered the same way. In fact, if you can imagine a spanner to throw in the works, very complex application requirements will probably throw it. So you can pick MV and get started and eventually it will start to get messy. You may have a very large amount of Controllery logic such as wiring up event callbacks and orchestrating request handling stuck inside Views (like MVC-less PHP) at which point you would want to break that out to manage it better.

The nightmares you refer to are probably those of developers who started with MV and ended up running up against the limits of simpler patterns and been left in dead ends with huuuuge amounts of technical debt to swap to MVC or something else. Given the nature of having to cope with HTTP and its idiosyncrasies, and the complexity of HTML and CSS and everything you have to deal with there, and databases and persistence, let alone business logic, I think MVC is almost always justified for web apps.

Focused little gems that only have a few classes to deal with, fill a specific need and whose component views are unlikely to be reused in any other context? I wouldn't be so strict about it.

Comment: Thanks, that all makes sense. I wasn't so much getting at "What bad things happen when Views aren't isolated from Models" - more just "are there any exceptions?" and it sounds like, yeah, in simple cases, there are exceptions. This particular app is basically just a vanilla spree store - just with a small handful of simple additions / customisations (such as this slider). So, I think this is a case where the simple approach is OK. But I'll look into Rob's way for future reference.

Comment: OK. Well in summary, there are exceptions and it's complicated. ;-)

Comment: Josh, you linked an article in a parallel Twitter convo and I feel like it's worth putting here for others' benefit, should they stumble across this page. I think it is very relevant:  http://www.sandimetz.com/blog/2014/05/28/betting-on-wrong

Answer (score 3):

I would not, mostly because your view is making a pile of assumptions that are going to be a pain to change later. Your view is assuming that it's using:

- an ActiveRecord class,
- with certain table columns,
- with other objects it's directly calling the properties of.

Here's my take on a view:

```
<% if slides.count > 0 %>
  <section id="slideshow">
    <ul class="slide">
      <% slides.each do |s| %>
        <li>
          <h1><%= s.name %></h1>
          <%= link_to image_tag(s.image_url), url_for(s.link) %>
        </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
    <a title="<%= t(:previous) %>" class="slider-prev"><%= t(:previous)%></a>
    <a title="<%= t(:next) %>" class="slider-next"><%= t(:next) %></a>
  </section>
<% end %>
```

And with a presenter:

```
# eg. app/presenters/slide_presenter.rb
class SlidePresenter
  extend Forwardable
  def initialize(slide)
    @slide = slide
  end

  def_delegator :@slide, :name, :slide_name
  def_delegator :@slide, :link, :slide_link

  def image_url
    @slide.slide_image.url
  end
end
```

And the controller action itself:

```
slides = Spree::Slide.published
                     .order('position ASC')
                     .map {|s| SlidePresenter.new(s) }
render 'theview', locals: { slides: slides }
```

The benefits of using a Presenter instead of directly using the model in the view is that it restricts how the model is used. Instead of calling any of the hundreds of methods on the ActiveRecord model (with all the variations in parameters), you know exactly how it's being used because you've only defined four methods on the presenter.

(Hiding the model behaviour behind the presenter also gives you an *interface* that doesn't change: that is, changing the model means changing the guts of the presenter itself, but not all the views that *use* the presenter.)

I'm not a big fan of the direct ActiveRecord business in the controller in my example above, but you can choose to move it into something like a FetchOrderedSlides service class or helper method, further restricting the known uses of the hundreds of methods on Slides to a handful in very specific parts of your codebase.

Comment: Although I'm very new to this Presenter and Service objects stuff, I can see the benefit what you've done there, decoupling the view / slider from the fetching of the data it uses. However, on this project, those assumptions (ActiveRecord class, certain table columns, etc) are basically fair enough assumptions for the foreseeable future. And avoiding those assumptions means introducing a few new concepts & abstractions. I do wonder if taking that step is better left to the time when (and if) those original assumptions do change.

Comment: Fair enough. Speaking of "all the views" from my edit above – you only have one view to start with, but you reap the benefits as soon as you add the second. You might defer adding in the presenter for this reason, if you're the sole maintainer and know you add the abstraction later.

Comment: Rob, so interacting with a model / database from a view is OK if it's going through a helper method or service object? As in, it's not the case that ALL database calls should be done within the controller (or, within the controller via service objects)?

Comment: It's /okay/ in the sense that it'll work, and you know how to improve your approach if you need to expand it, but I wouldn't do it personally because I don't know who's going to come along next and try to maintain or extend it (even solo-maintainer OSS projects).